# Maintaining an array of ints representing option indices in Angularjs

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I have an array of ints in my model which is meant to represent the indices of a list of options the user will pick from using a select list.  The idea is there's a list you can expand and you keep picking things from the select list.  I have code along these lines:

```
    <ul>
      <li ng-repeat="item in model.arrayOfInts">
        <select ng-model="item"
                ng-options="choice.id as choice.name for choice in common.options">
          <option value="">---</option>
        </select>
        <button ng-click="model.arrayOfInts.splice($index, 1)" type="button">
          Delete
        </button>
      </li>
    </ul>

    <button ng-click="model.arrayOfInts.push(null)" type="button">
      Add
    </button>
```

I have two problems which seem to be related:

- the `ng-model` does not seem to actually bind properly; if I inspect the scope I can see that newly-pushed members of `arrayOfInt` are still set to `null` even after I select something from the select menu representing them.
- When I attempt to push another item into the array, Angular complains that duplicate options are not allowed.

What is the proper way to do what I'm trying to do?

[JSFiddle sample](http://jsfiddle.net/8rLvtumf/)

Comment: "it's still set to `null`" < what is set to null?

Comment: @brettvd Sorry; what I mean is that the value of the array at that index is still set to null, even after selecting an option from the select list.  So, assuming I start off with an empty array, if I click "Add," select a value, and click "Add" again, I end up with `[null, null]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first issue ("ng-model does not bind properly") is because you're not targeting the array with ng-model. `item` in your ng-repeat is a new property on the scope (created by the ng-repeat). It doesn't contain any information on where it came from (arrayOfInts).

The following code tells ng-model to point to the right index of the array, rather than a new scope property.

```
<select ng-model="model.arrayOfInts[$index]"
            ng-options="choice.id as choice.name for choice in common.options">
```

The second issue is because model.arrayOfInts can have multiple duplicates in it (click "add" twice and you've just added two nulls). Angular needs some way to tell the difference between them, so you need to add a tracking property, in this case $index.

```
<li ng-repeat="item in model.arrayOfInts track by $index">
```

Comment: That seems obvious now that I'm reading your explanation.  Thanks.